# Python process for scraping in GCP Compute Engine being suspended for Crypto Mining

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I receive this email and my VM instance gets suspended. It is an airflow server that runs multiple processes including one DAG which scrapes of 5k - 10k separate links and extracts body from it - this is done concurrently by 500 different connections which is what I'm suspecting is raising this particular issue. I receive this particular email after 24 hours of running and my VM gets suspended.

```
Dear Developer,
We've detected that your Google Cloud Project is engaging in cryptocurrency mining, resulting in the suspension of all project resources displaying this behavior.

This activity violates the Google Cloud Platform Terms of Service or the Terms of Service of the Google API you may be using.

We recommend that you review this activity to determine if it is intended. Cryptocurrency mining is often an indication of the use of fraudulent accounts and payment instruments, and we require verification in order to mine cryptocurrency on our platform.

Therefore if you wish to continue engaging in cryptocurrency mining, you must apply for an Invoiced Billing Account. Additional information is available in the Cloud Security Help Center.

To regain access to your suspended resources please submit an appeal:

Sign in to as the project owner, click Request an appeal below, and fill in the following details:

Possible trigger of this activity
If the behavior is intentional, please provide the Invoiced Billing Account ID
If you believe the project may have been compromised by a third party, describe your concerns
Learn more about policy violations and appeals

If you need further help, reach out to the Google Cloud Platform Community Support Forum. If you have a support package, file a ticket through the Support Center.

You may have received an earlier warning about a possible suspension of resources if this violation wasn't corrected. If you didn't receive a warning before this suspension, it was because the project's behavior was seriously impacting the service of other users.
```

This is the code which I'm suspecting is creating the issue

```
out = []
CONNECTIONS = 500
TIMEOUT = 5

def do_request(url):
    try:
        requests.head(url, verify=False, timeout=10, headers=headers)
    except Exception:
        return "", 404

    try:
        res = requests.get(url, verify=False, timeout=10, headers=headers)
        content = extract_content(res.content)
        return content, res.status_code
    except Exception:
        return "", 404


def gen_text_dragnet(article, timeout):
    content, status_code = do_request(article["url"])
    article.update(body=content[:500], status_code=status_code)
    return status_code


def extract_body():
    """
    Processing broken URLs are a huge pain in the ass
    """
    global_init()
    try:
        articles = Article.objects.filter(
            status_code__exists=False)[:5000]
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise

    print("extracting bodies from {} articles".format(len(articles)))

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=CONNECTIONS) as executor:
        future_to_url = (executor.submit(gen_text_dragnet, article, TIMEOUT)
                         for article in articles)
        time1 = time.time()
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
            try:
                data = future.result()
            except Exception as exc:
                data = str(type(exc))
            finally:
                out.append(data)
                print(str(len(out)), end="\r")

        time2 = time.time()

    print(f'Took {time2-time1:.2f} s')
    print(pd.Series(out).value_counts())
```

This has happened multiple times and every time I submit an appeal, I get no response and I have to delete and re-create the instance. That is really annoying and isn't sustainable for the project. What can I do about this?

Answer (score 1):

StackOverflow isn't the right channel to solve issues like this.

The best option for you could be contact [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support) because they has the possibility to inspect your project and provide you further instructions. If you don't have a support contract yet in such case you could ask for one time courtesy from support.

If you don't wan't to contact support in that way you can try to open a case at Google Issue Tracker under [this](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/new?component=491456&template=1161077) **private component**  and provide project name, email and as many details as possible.